# Is there any way to call @Scheduled annotation in main method in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scheduler

I just want to run my spring boot main method periodically by using @scheduler annotation. I have specified some additional code which will perform some pre-action before it enables REST services.

```
@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootJDBCApp {

    @Autowired
    ITest testService;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception  {
        PersistenceValidation.cloneGit();
        PersistenceValidation.dataPersistance();
        PersistenceValidation.cleanUp();
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication
                .run(SpringBootJDBCApp.class);
        ITest testService = context.getBean(ITestService.class);
        testService.getAllData();
    }
}
```

I want to run the above main method every 10seconds once. and Added @Schedule annotation at main method. But It throws an exception:

> Expected behavior as per doc @Scheduler should be called a method which doesn't have args[]

I wanna use `@Scheduler` annotation in main method as below:

```
@Scheduled(initialDelay = 1000, fixedRate = 10000)
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    PersistenceValidation.cloneGit();
    PersistenceValidation.dataPersistance();
    PersistenceValidation.cleanUp();
    ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(SpringBootJDBCApp.class);
    ITest testService = context.getBean(ITestService.class);
    testService.getAllData();
}
```

**Error**:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springBootJDBCApp': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'main': Only no-arg methods may be annotated with @Scheduled

Is there any other way to achieve this task? I wanna run the entire things which are mentioned in the main method periodically.

Any leads?

Comment: Please have a look at the question. I updated that

Comment: Why don't you just refactor the code into a method that supports the annotation ?

Comment: I did now... Really thanks for your idea...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scheduled method annotated with [`@Scheduled`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html) annotation must have no arguments because the annotation doesn't provide any input. The Spring-docs of [`@Scheduled`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html) sais:

> The annotated method must expect no arguments. It will typically have a void return type; if not, the returned value will be ignored when called through the scheduler.

You annotated the method `public static void main(String args[])` which has an array as an argument. You have to just wrap the content in the `main(String args[])` into a different method. Note you don't use `args[]` at all.